# Создать постоянную горизонтальную линию в TChart

Tags: c++, embarcadero

Мне нужно создать горизонтальную линию при чертении кривой в одной и той же диаграмме.

Я пытаюсь так, функция для создания горизонтальной линии:

```
void CReadOutTemperature::drawVerticle()
            {
                int X0Pos = DlgMainWindow->ChartTemperatureCurve->ChartRect.Left;
                int X1Pos = X0Pos + DlgMainWindow->ChartTemperatureCurve->ChartRect.Width();
                double YVal = ReachValue/10.0;
                int YPos = DlgMainWindow->ChartTemperatureCurve->Axes->Left->CalcPosValue(YVal);
                DlgMainWindow->ChartTemperatureCurve->Canvas->DoHorizLine(X0Pos, X1Pos, YPos);
            }
```

Так как это `Thread`, я использую для рисования кривой и этой линии `Synchronize`. А это функция которая вызывается в `Synchronize`:

```
void __fastcall CReadOutTemperature::UpdateCaption()
{
 static UINT start_time = GetTickCount();
if(GetTickCount()-start_time>=1000)
    {
        start_time = GetTickCount();

        DlgMainWindow->ChartTemperatureCurve->Series[0]->AddY(CurrentTemperature/10.0,"",clRed);
        drawVerticle();
    }
}
```

А буквально на секунду вижу границу, которая находтся на `у = 10`, но потом она исчезает.

Как можно эту проблему решить?

Answer (score 1):

Создайте линию в Chart-диалоге, обзовите ее Ser1 Затем в программе:
const double x1 = 5.0, x2 = 125.0, y = 73.0;
Ser->AddXY(x1, y);
Ser->AddXY(x2, y);
Получится горизонтальная линия, если я Вас верно понял.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Не совсем все верно так как значение **х** динамичны, и значит что **ось - х** всегда растет. Так как прямая которую вы описали действительна только на нынешние границы **так как const** . Я пока что не найти решение